# Any way to change recommended resolution for all users on a Mac (preferably via Terminal)?

Tags: imac, display, preferences, projector

I work on a college campus with a number of iMacs hooked up to projectors. For some reason, after imaging, they all default to 800x600 resolution on both the iMacs and the projectors, despite their shared maximum display resolutions. Is there any way to automatically tell the Mac to default the resolution to something higher and maintain that for all users regardless of what it's hooked up to? Alternately, is there any way I can change the default resolution for all users after the imaging process is complete?

I've found the com.apple.preference.displays file in /Library/Preferences/ByHost, but because it relies on the machine's UUID I don't think it will allow me to push that out remotely...

Comment: Would simply deleting the offending preference file and subsequently forcing a reboot correct the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this little app before and it works quite well.

http://www.mowlem-enterprises.co.uk/screenutil/ScreenUtil_v1.0.zip

You'd just throw that into your image in your terminal path somewhere (/usr/sbin) then you can ARD shell command the terminal command you need or script it into the image.

Comment: The link's broken...

Comment: Sorry it wasn't my app. Not sure where to get it now.